# Firefox: Right Click Open link in New Tab not working

Tags: firefox

Some since after noon Firefox Right Click "Open link in New Tab" not working

Comment: Why did you down-vote ???
Isn't it better to try to help the person?
I'm also facing this problem - from few days, under Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox 16.0.1.
And after googling and coming here - my favorite website - i would be hapier to find the answers i'm usually find here, instead of just downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related with Firebug update 1.10.4 - restarting Firefox should help.